# Reported cluster size of an exFAT SD card varies between wmic and diskpart in Windows 11

Tags: windows-11

I'm trying to figure out the cluster / block / allocation unit size of a microSD card (F:).

wmic (I have no idea why lines are being skipped):

```
> C:\Users\admin>wmic volume get driveletter,blocksize 
> BlockSize DriveLetter 
> 4096       C: 
> 4096 
> 4096       D: 
> 2048 
> 131072     F: 
> 4096
```

Diskpart:

> DISKPART> filesystems
> Current File System
>
> Type                 : exFAT
> Allocation Unit Size : 128K
> Flags :0 0000000

What am I doing wrong? I'm assuming that cluster / block / allocation unit size are all the same thing, but that understanding appears to be wrong.